# Computer Crash when Charging Cable Unplugged

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, charging

On my laptop I get crashes every time I unplug my charging cable. It wasn't always like this, but has become like this over some time.

Basically, I unplug the cord and it turns off instantly. It isn't a successful shutdown, rather a crash. Is it a battery problem or is it something else?

Comment: Test whether the box will boot while on battery.  If not then it's a problem with the battery (though it could be a bad connection or something in the charger circuit, vs the battery itself).

Comment: If it turns off instantly, it's not crashing. A computer that is off cannot crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like that probably because your battery is old, and has been used a lot.
Basically, battery's capacity decreases over time.
Try using a new battery.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I thought it would be because of that.

Comment: Was glad to help. If my answer satisfies you, please mark it with the V on the right.

Comment: @matan129: like this: V